# Fully Array alternative

Tags: c++, performance, assembly

When I tried to create my own alternative to classic array, I saw, that into disassembly code added one instruction: `mov edx,dword ptr [myarray]`. Why this additional instruction was added?

I want to use my functionality of my alternative, but do not want to lose performance! How to resolve this question? Every processor cycle is important for this application.

For example:

```c
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    array1[i] = i;
    array2[i] = 10 - i;
}
```

Assembly (classic int arrays):

```
mov edx, dword ptr [ebp-480h]  
mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-480h]  
mov dword ptr array1[edx*4], eax  

mov ecx, 10
sub ecx, dword ptr [ebp-480h]
mov edx, dword ptr [ebp-480h]
mov dword ptr array2[edx*4], ecx
```

Assembly (my class):

```
mov edx,dword ptr [array1]
mov eax,dword ptr [ebp-43Ch]
mov ecx,dword ptr [ebp-43Ch]
mov dword ptr [edx+eax*4], ecx

mov edx, 10
sub edx, dword ptr [ebp-43Ch]
mov eax, dword ptr [array2]
mov ecx, dword ptr [ebp-43Ch]
mov dword ptr [eax+ecx*4], edx
```

Comment: one instruction is a loss of performance??

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can say what why that "extra" instruction was added without seeing your code and what you're comparing it to.

Comment: I'm not sure, but size of code must be a constant (without additional funtionality).

Comment: Let me know how you get on optimizing C arrays, I'm genuinely interested.

Comment: Updated. I do not want to optimize. Size of code must be a constant (for operator []).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One instruction is not a loss of performance with today's processors. I would not worry about it and instead suggest you read Coding Horror's [article on micro optimization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

However, that instruction is just moving the first index (myarray+0) to `edx` so it can be used.